# How can I access Google App Engine endpoints API from Python application with use OAuth?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

How can I access Google App Engine endpoints API for Python (not web, android, ios)?

I read this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/clients/js/add_auth) but it not explains it enough to understand this.

As I found on serve side I can use such code to identify user:

```
@endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, Greeting,
                  path='hellogreeting/authed', http_method='POST',
                  name='greetings.authed')
def greeting_authed(self, request):
    current_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
    email = (current_user.email() if current_user is not None
             else 'Anonymous')
    return Greeting(message='hello %s' % (email,))
```

[Full code of API example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python/blob/master/helloworld_api.py)

**How can I connect from Python client to this API and call 'hellogreeting/authed' with authentication `current_user != None`.**

Can you share some code how to do it?

```
app_id = 'xxx'
user = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'
callAPI(app_id, user, password, 'hellogreeting/authed')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your App Engine instance to be able to serve your API. I would recommend you create a separate module dedicated to your API, like explained in these docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/api_server.

Once everything is correctly set up on the server side, you can call your API using something like: `http://your-module.your-app.appspot.com/_ah/spi/hellogreeting/authed`.

If you're using the development server, things are a little bit different for accessing modules, but once you know which port number the App Engine development server has assigned to your API module, you can reach it locally using: `http://localost:<api_module_port_#>/_ah/spi/hellogreeting/authed`.

Hope this helped.